# wrap numbers in span tag javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, numbers

I have this code

```html
<div class="NumbersDiv">
<p> The Number <span class=class1>150</span> is <b>same</b> as <b><span>25</span></b> * 6 </p>
<p> The Number <i>175</i> is <b>same</b> as <b><span>25</span></b> * <span>7</span> </p>
<p> The Number <span class=class1>200</span> is <b>same</b> as <b><span>25</span></b> * 8 </p>
</div>
<button>Numbers</button>
```

Problem is, When I click on `Numbers` button I want to enclose all the numbers in `NumbersDiv` in a `span` tag but not that numbers which already enclosed in `span` tag.
NOTE: It will be more helpful if someone provide a demo on jsfiddle.

Comment: are you wanting to get all number 150 25 6  175  25  7

Comment: can you please share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @EMM, why do you never accept answers? I want to help, but why should I bother if you can't bother to accept answers? Btw, downvote wasnt me

Comment: @AmmarCSE Sorry I forgot, but from now on I promise that I will, please answer it...!

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla see the answer below.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you

Comment: @EMM Please go back and mark an accepted answer (if appropriate) on your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rxp = new RegExp("(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+))", "gm");
    $(document.activeElement).keyup(function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 13){
      e.preventDefault();
      var ths = $(document.activeElement);
      $("<p class='Paragraph' contenteditable='true'></p>").insertAfter( document.activeElement ).focus(); 
      $(ths).children(".highlight").contents().unwrap();
      var content = $(ths).html();
         $(ths).html(content.replace(rxp,"<span class='highlight' ondragover='event.preventDefault()' ondrop='drop(event)'>$1</span>"));
     };
     $(document.activeElement).children(".highlight").contents().unwrap();
     var content = $(document.activeElement).html();
        $(document.activeElement).html(content.replace(rxp,"<span class='highlight' ondragover='event.preventDefault()' ondrop='drop(event)'>$1</span>"));
        while($(document.activeElement).children().children().length > 0){
     $(document.activeElement).children().children().contents().unwrap();
     }
       });
```

Comment: is this the answer ? or is part of the question ?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Partof the question

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. This code works but the problem occurs when some numbers have span tag like `<span data-var="asd" data-min="2" data-max="100" contenteditable="false" class="TKAdjustableNumber">12321</span>`